# Unable to change the button color of confirm box in Bootbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

In Bootbox, I am unable to change the button color of confiem box, please help me out

here is my code:

```
bootbox.confirm('This action removes all partners from this project and resets all existing stock distribution. <br /> <br /> Do you wish to continue?','Cancel','Remove', function (result) {
    if (result == true) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootbox` allows you to add classes to the buttons. See the following snippet for a working example.  Put whatever styles you want in your css file, or better yet stick with the standard bootstrap colors for consistency.  In the example I use the btn-danger and btn-default bootstrap classes as well as pull-right and pull-left, but you can use whatever classes you wish

If you are still having problems perhaps you have a mismatch between bootbox and bootstrap and jquery versions?

```js
bootbox.confirm({
  message: 'This action removes all partners from this project and resets all existing stock distribution. <br /> <br /> Do you wish to continue?',
  buttons: {
    'cancel': {
      label: 'Cancel',
      className: 'btn-default pull-left'
    },
    'confirm': {
      label: 'Remove',
      className: 'btn-danger pull-right'
    }
  },
  callback: function(result) {
    if (result) {
      // whatever you want to do here
      console.log(result)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Mitch, Thanks for your answer. I tried this, I am getting empty modal with 2  buttons remove and cancel. message is not displaying and also buttons are not changing

Comment: could you either mark the above answer as correct (it does work after all) or at least let us know how else we can help?

Comment: Sorry its not working for me. i think because I used bootstrap 2.0 and jquery 1.8 so I am using bootbox v3.3,0. I cant able update bootstrap and jquery because of conflicts. Is there any way to solve my problem without upgrading the versions??

Comment: I believe in v3.3.0 you had to say `"class": ...` rather than `className:  ....`  I can't get a consistent set of cdn sources to try it... hopefully that will work

Comment: I updated bootbox version to 4.4.0. Finally its working now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, some days we are just plumbers looking around for the parts that fit.

Answer (score 0):

you can using CSS

```
<style>
     .bootbox-confirm div div div button.btn-primary{
         background-color: orange
     }
 </style>
```